# Azure App Service deploy task does not always copy `appsettings.json` to App Service

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-appservice

In the Azure App Service deploy task I specify the `JSON variable substitution` as `**/appsettings.json` and I can see in the log that the substitutions were made.  However, every-so-often the `appsettings.json` containing the substituted variable values is not copied as it not seen as changed.  This results in the original templated `appsettings.json` file being deployed and *that* causes the App Service to not start up correctly.  Oddly enough, it seems to occur most often when the release is automatically triggered.  When run manually it seems to copy the file.

It would've been nice to be able to simply perform a replace on a templated `appsettings.json` file and then copy that to the App Service but I have not been able to find any way to do that... perhaps it isn't possible.

If there is another way that would be easier to get environment-specific `appsettings.json` files deployed to an App Service that would be great.

In the meantime, it would be first prize if the substituted file is *always* deployed.

There is a `-useCheckSum` argument provided to the task if that makes any difference.

Comment: Nowadays I almost exclusively use "run from package" deployment which cannot suffer from these issues. Is this an option for you?

Comment: @AlexAIT I've logged a ticket with Microsoft.  I'll see what they come back with.  I'll take a look at "run from package" but I seem to recall an issue with that for us, but I cannot remember what that was.  Once I get my way all our App Services will be hosted containers.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have unchecked the `Remove files at destination` option.

[image]

Already existing files get deleted if we check this option during the deployment.

> There is a `-useCheckSum` argument provided to the task if that makes any difference.

If `usechecksum` option is enabled, the files get deployed only if there are any changes.

If you want to deploy the `appsettings.json` file every time, then disable the `usechecksum` option.

Thanks @Alex AIT for the comment.

> "run from package" deployment which cannot suffer from these issues. Is this an option for you?

Yes, by using   `Run from package` option we can avoid this type of issues.
All the files are packaged in a zip folder and will be available after deployment.

[image]

> If there is another way that would be easier to get environment-specific `appsettings.json` files deployed to an App Service that would be great.

We have an option to store `App Settings` in App Configuration.
Refer [Push settings](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-app-configuration/push-kv-devops-pipeline.md) and [Pull settings](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-app-configuration/pull-key-value-devops-pipeline.md) with Azure Pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

I was on a call with Microsoft support and the engineer suggested I use a [FileTransform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/file-transform-v2?view=azure-pipelines) task prior to invoking the Azure App Service deploy task and remove substitutions from the deploy task altogether.

That did the trick.

Since the file transform task effectively replaces the `appsettings.json` in the `zip` file with the one containing the substituted values *that* is what is going to be deployed.  I would've expected something similar from the deploy task but as long as I have a solution I'm happy.